# Which EOL should I use in general?

Tags: web, eol

I wondered if there was a EOL (end of line) to be privileged between `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` (if my enumeration is right).

The question is in general and, especially about what a webserver should serve?

**Bonus:** if you can also tell me about Python specificity if such exist.

**PS:** As my question is, in a hand generic and in the other specific, I didn't know if I should have also tagged my question with the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag or not. Let me know.

**EDIT:** And is it just a matter of operating system related prob or is there some programs (or specifications) requiring or advising to use one more than the others? I found surprisingly not a lot of information about them. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For the web, \n doesn't do anything, you need a

```
<br>
```

For python, \n should be fine, but if you want to be REALLY safe, you could use

```
import os
os.linesep #this is the newline character on the OS that the code is running on
```

EDIT: formatting